# File System watcher in Windows Service or Console Application?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

I am implementing a file system watcher, my requirement is to watch for a given local folder on a machine and then do a small task (for example open a certain page in web browser). The file(s) in the given directory would be generated randomly sometimes every two hours or four etc.   This tool should be automated in the sense that a user does not have to start it.   So my question is, Should I implement this in a windows service which always will be running or in a console application.Preference is to do it in a console application but then it would need to started by a user right?  Please advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can automatically call any type of application (Console, Windows, etc.).  What it gets down to with a Windows Service is whether you want it to be running before anyone logs in.

Only a Windows service runs while no one is logged in.  A console application (while it can be set to run on login) must have someone log in in order to run.

Comment: I see, so by using console application, I could add an entry in the registry right? and If I wanted to stop it then remove the entry? thanks

Comment: Yes you can either put the file in the Startup folder or use the `Run` or `RunOnce` registry values.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376977(v=vs.85).aspx